# How to change a contentscript variable on click on the icon of a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to change a variable in my contentscript file by clicking on the icon of my Chrome extension. Do you know how I can do it?

Here is a sample of my code :

### background.js :

```
var myVariable = false;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) { //Fired when User Clicks ICON

  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
      "file": "zen-reading.js"
  }, function () {
      console.log("Script Executed .. ");
  });
  if (myVariable === false) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      code: 'myVariable = ' + true + ';'
    });
    myVariable = true;
  }
  else {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      code: 'myVariable = ' + false + ';'
    });
    zenMode = myVariable;
  }

});
```

### contentscript.js :

```
if (myVariable === true) {
  doSomething();
}

if (myVariable === false) {
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Method 1: divide the content script in two and depending on `myVariable` inject one of them.
- Method 2: inject the code that sets the variable prior to injecting the script file:

  ```
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
      code: "var myVariable=" + myVariable.toString()
  }, function(results) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "zen-reading.js"}, function(results) {
          ..........
      });
  });
  ```

  In case it's not a boolean/number use JSON:

  ```
  code: 'var myVariable=JSON.parse("' + JSON.stringify(myVariable) + '")'
  ```
- Method 3: inject the file once and use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). This is slightly more complicated because you will need to check first (using `executeScript` that will look for a variable that your content script should define) if the active tab has the content script injected which may not be the case if the user navigated to another url in the same tab.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the second method and obtained the expected result :)